# Does a thickness of a bubble become constant over time?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bubbles

Assuming no gravity, imagine you have a bubble floating in the air, does its thickness have a tendency to become constant?

State a bit differently, if we start with a bubble with variable thickness, will the thickness equalize over time?

What is the mechanism to cause this?

---

I'm expecting that the thickness equalizes, otherwise I can not imagine how could be a bubble stable.

However, it can not be a simple argument with pressure and surface tension. Imagine a perfect ball of water with a perfect ball of air inside of it(a bubble :D). Moving around the inner ball of air does change the curvature or volume, therefore there can not be any force response if we consider only pressure or surface tension.

For soap bubbles, there is probably some pressure increase near the surface because the concentration of sulfactant is much higher on the surface then in the bulk. Unfortunately, I do not really understand these things.

Comment: In a air-liquid bubble there is actually two surfaces that surface tension acts on; the inner and the outer surface. To be stable the tension on both surface need to be in equilibrium. I can imagine this can only be the case if the bubble is of near uniform thickness.